# Is there a component inside the stun gun that limits current?

Tags: current, components

Stun guns in electronic terms are basically boost converters that allow voltage to boost to a very high voltage. Using only 9V battery, it would boost the voltage to million of volts. Where does the current go? Is there a limiter inside that prevents current from spiking up and might possibly kill someone if used on them? If there is, what component prevents the current from going up? If there isn't, what happens to the current that goes through the circuit?

Comment: 1. The resistance of the target's body limits the current. 2. The stored energy is limited if the voltage is limited, and this limits the possible damage done to the target.

Comment: @ThePhoton So the current is limited by natural causes? If the stun gun was applied to a body or a circuit with small resistance, the current will go up. Thus the I=V/R?

Comment: Yes, but the duration of the discharge would also be less, so no more actual energy delivered to the target.

Comment: Also, millions of volts are known marketing snake oil.  The dielectric of air has about a 10kV/cm breakdown voltage, so for a million volts you'd need 100cm between the stun tips (!)

Comment: The circuitry is limited in the maximum amount of energy it can transform to a high voltage.  It is self limiting and intended to be non lethal. There will be some deliberate or unintended breakdown of the capacitively or inductively stored charge (per switching cycle) if the voltage climbs too high.  If no discharge occurs the voltage will reach some saturation value if DC or alternate if AC.

Comment: @while1 So the output voltage is also dependent on the amount of space between the two metals?

Comment: @KalleMP So what you are saying is that the stun gun only has a few moments of let's say 1 million volts until it saturates down to the same energy of the battery?

Comment: @HenryLachica, there is only a energetic discharge for a brief moment due to the magnetic or capacitive storage.  When a circuit has been made the energy output is equal to the energy input.  Short high voltage pulses do not take much energy and that is why the debilitating effects can be maintained even though the average energy transfer is pretty low.

Comment: Here is a PDF with tazer waveforms and stuff. http://cironline.org/sites/default/files/legacy/files/2006-EffectsofCocaineIntoxicationontheThresholdforStunGunInductionofVentricularFibrillation.pdf

Answer (score 2):

So firstly the claims of millions of volts is complete b.s. As already stated air resistance is around 10kV/cm, this means if the prongs of the device are 1cm apart it cannot get above 10kV. Why? Because the charge will arc between the prongs and the voltage will drop to zero.

How does it work? Well they can have various designs, but essentially the property used is the high frequency oscillation between a capacitor and an inductor that occurs when you disconnect the input. It will create very high voltage spikes and when the inductor is the primary winding of a transformer, you get even bigger spikes on the secondary winding.

Control over the delivery to the target has two factors. Firstly there are the components chosen, how many windings in the transformer, resistance etc which set what the maximum output can be. Secondly there is the frequency that the device delivers the voltage pulses. You only get a pulse each time the input is disconnected and its very easy to control the switching frequency. I'm reasonably sure most (all?) models use some sort of feedback to adjust the pulse frequency on the fly while the device is operating.

So the answer is: There are multiple parts of the design which place a limit on the current delivered. The major limits will be designed into the specs of the transformer used and the pulse frequency delivered. I would guess most commercial designs have a micro controller with feed back driving some sort of pulse timing algorithm. Though you just have a fixed oscillator I suppose.

And to be clear, they deliver somewhere between 10-20,000V. No where near the millions claimed.

I should also say that while it is very easy to build a hand-held, battery powered device that will deliver high voltages into anything it touches. Building one that will incapacitate but not kill that thing is pretty difficult. You are riding a very fine line and stun-guns are not well named.

They really should be called 'Low leathality' guns. Because even your best commercial device that has been tested on a whole bunch of animals to get the settings just right, still kill people a bunch of the time.

(Hence if you're asking this because you want to build your own, don't. You WILL kill someone with it.)

Answer (score 1):

A stun gun uses a capacitor to store charge and the capacitor is constantly being recharged to deliver a series of high-voltage pulses. It stores a high potential.

There is little current similar to how static electricity has a high voltage but a very low electrical charge. The 9V is boosted to thousands of volts by a transformer, and if a transformer is boosting voltage then current goes down.

Comment: So everything falls down to the capacitor that stores all the energy from the battery? How does it send energy that fast in such a short period of time?